# ActiveRecord touch(:column) always also updates :updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got pretty much the same problem as this guy: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/197440.

I'm trying to touch a column (`:touched_at`) without having it auto-update `:updated_at`, but watching the SQL queries, it always updates both to the current time.

I thought it might be something to do with the particular model I was using it on, so I tried a couple different ones with the same result.

Does anyone know what might be causing it to always set `:updated_at` when touching a different column? `touch` uses `write_attribute` internally, so it shouldn't be doing this.

**Edit:**

Some clarification... the Rails 2.3.5 docs for `touch` state that "If an attribute name is passed, that attribute is used for the touch instead of the updated_at/on attributes." But mine isn't acting that way. Perhaps it's a case of the docs having drifted away from the actual state of the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You pretty much want to write custom SQL:

```
def touch!
  self.class.update_all({:touched_at => Time.now.utc}, {:id => self.id})
end
```

This will generate this SQL:

```
UPDATE posts SET touched_at = '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000' WHERE id = 1
```

which is what you're after. If you call #save, this will end up calling [#create_with_timestamps](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L42) or [#update_with_timestamps](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L56), and these are what update the updated_on/updated_at/created_on/created_at columns.

By the way, the source for [#touch](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L27) says it all.

Comment: This seems to be the only way. Looks like the Rails 2.3.5 docs are just wrong. I'd add to you answer that I could put the `touch!` method in a callback on the model to finish replicating the functionality of ActiveRecord `belongs_to`'s `:touch => :column` (which I think uses `before_save` and `before_destroy`, but I'd have to check the source).

Comment: `.update_all({:touched_at => Time.now.utc}, {:id => self.id})` has been deprecated in favor of `self.class.where(id: self.id).update_all(touched_at: Time.now.utc)`